# Parallax with mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, parallax.js

I'm trying to 'transform' elements, img here when the mouse moves on the page. I have integrated a vanilla code to create this effect and thought I understoond it but it seems I was wrong. The element from the code snippet is the orange square (3.png), but I want to apply this effect on the human pic (2.png) behind aswell and can't figure out how. (here's the full code as I don't rly know what's messed up except for my whole architecture prbly: https://github.com/KPq66dw8L/b-code-fiverr)

```
<section class="container bot-container-img">
<img class="layer closeUp" src="images/1.png" data-speeed="2" alt="">
<img class="layer ellipse2" src="images/2.png" data-speeed="-5" alt="">
<img class="layer" src="images/images/3.png" data-speed="2" alt=""> 
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.bot-container-img {
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
section img {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", parallax);

function parallax(e){
    this.querySelectorAll('.layer').forEach(layer => {
        const speed = layer.getAttribute('data-speed')

        const x = (window.innerWidth - e.pageX*speed)/100
        const y = (window.innerHeight - e.pageY*speed)/100

        layer.style.transform = `translateX(${x}px) translateY(${y}px)`
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few minor errors I corrected:

- typo `data-speeed="2"` corrected to `data-speed="2"`
- I preferred `getBoundingClientRect()` over `window.innerWidth` / `window.innerHeight`
- The items being effected by parallax are centered using `left`, `top`, `width`, `height`, and negative `margin-left` and `margin-top` - this allows the `transform.translate` property to translate them relative to their centers
- I wrapped all the logic into a nice `applyParallax` function, in case you wish to apply it to multiple `section` elements

I also had to make some changes to get this to work with stackoverflow's snippet system:

- Instead of `<img>` I used `<div class="img"></div>`, with css to colour different `div.img` elements distinctly
- I decreased the size of the `div.img` elements to make the effect more visible in the small window
- I increased the values for `data-speed` to make the effect more obvious
- I made the `html` and `body` elements fill the whole viewport (and the `section` element fills the whole `body` element)

```js
let applyParallax = section => {
  
  section.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {

    let { width, height } = section.getBoundingClientRect();
    let offX = e.pageX - (width * 0.5);
    let offY = e.pageY - (height * 0.5);

    for (let layer of document.querySelectorAll('.img')) {
      const speed = layer.getAttribute('data-speed')
      const x = (offX * speed) / 100;
      const y = (offY * speed) / 100;
      layer.style.transform = `translateX(${x}px) translateY(${y}px)`
    }

  });
  section.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {

    for (let layer of document.querySelectorAll('.img')) {
      layer.style.transform = `translateX(0px) translateY(0px)`
    }

  });
  
};
applyParallax(document.querySelector('section'));
```

```css
html, body { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; }
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
section > .img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 50%;
  width: 120px; height: 120px;
  margin-left: -60px; margin-top: -60px;
}
section > .img.r { background-color: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5); }
section > .img.g { background-color: rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.4); }
section > .img.b { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.3); }
```

```html
<section class="container bot-container-img">
  <div class="img r" data-speed="22"></div>
  <div class="img g" data-speed="-5"></div>
  <div class="img b" data-speed="32"></div>
</section>
```